# How can I remove excess tile mortar from grout lines?

Tags: tiling

I laid a tile floor in my bathroom and used too much mortar, which pushed up between the tiles.  There wasn't enough room for grout in some places, and now it looks messy and is difficult to keep clean.  Is there a way to remove some of the excess between the tiles?  I had though maybe I could soak it section by section with vinegar and then use a tool to dig some out.  Another option I can think of would be to do the same without the vinegar.  Does anyone have suggestions?  I'd rather not have to remove the whole thing and start over.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your grout gap, an oscillating tool with a grout blade could work well.

[image]

If your gaps are substantially wider, a narrow chisel might do the job.

I'd avoid any rotating tool as you're likely to slip and damage your tile.

Comment: +1 for "avoid any rotating tool". First thing that popped into my mind was my little SkilSaw with a masonry blade. Glad you got here first.

Comment: For a lighter touch, you can also find manual grout saws; just a handle with a blob of carbide bits: https://www.homedepot.com/s/grout%2520saw. I've also successfully used a carbide scorer used to scribe cement backer board. It's basically a single tooth of carbide. Power tools are definitely the way to go for more than just a few inches...

Comment: Feel free to post an answer, @spuck. No harm in that. Comments should be reserved for clarification questions, etc.

Comment: Would these tools work for removing the excess mortar as well as grout?  Thanks!